# Why is my Heroku client not connecting to Heroku Postgres db?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, sequelize.js

I'm relatively new to Node, and especially new to moving an app from dev to production environment.

I have a Node + Express + Sequelize client app hosted on Heroku, as well as a Postgres db resource connected to the app. The client runs fine for certain routes, and I have the Postgres database in the "resources" of my app. But the client returns `undefined` on the first SQL query (e.g. a GET request to `/books` route simply returns undefined).

I have tried setting `process.env.DATABASE_URL` in `app.js` to the database URI like this:

```
const postgres =
 "postgres://foo:bar@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/yyy";
process.env.DATABASE_URL = postgres;
```

I also tried manually changing "production" to test the production env in a development setting `const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production"`.

I've read through Heroku docs and various articles, but I'm not sure why I can't access the database except during development.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Please change your database credentials IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: Use `heroku pg:credentials:rotate` to do so. (Also, Heroku sets `process.env.DATABASE_URL` automatically for you; you should just access it.)

Comment: What makes you think it isn't connecting?

Comment: @jjanes because when I try to access a resource from the database it returns undefined and my app crashes.

Comment: If your app is so profoundly broken that it returns undefined rather than an actual error message, then you have an app problem.  You might also have a database problem, there is no way to know on this basis.